# ng-repeat update after build

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of events that gets build from a JSON call to my server. The list gets parsed through ng-repeat. I want to implement a like button for the event and if its liked, replace that with unlike.

```
<a ng-show='event.liked==null' ng-click="like(event.event_id)">Like</a>
<a ng-show='event.liked!=null' ng-click="unLike(event.event_id)">Unlike</a>
```

Everything works perfectly except I have to refresh the feed to show "Unlike". Is there a way I can update the specific list item at the index that was liked once clicked without the need to refresh.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

edit: adding like function & unlike function. All it does is send request to my server to like or unlike a specific event with the event_id and user token.

```
$scope.like = function (event_id) {
   var url = www.server.com?type=unlike&event_id=...
    $http.post(url).success(function (data) {
        console.log('success like');
        //I want it to update my index here
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('fail like');
    });
};
$scope.unLike = function (event_id) {
    var url = www.server.com?type=unlike&event_id=...
    $http.post(url).success(function (data) {
        console.log('success unlike');
        //I want it to update my index here
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('fail unlike');
    });
};
```

Comment: Post your `like` and `unlike` functions

Comment: Also, you can simplify your code by using `ng-hide='event.liked'` for the "Like" link and `ng-show='event.liked'` for the "Unlike" link.

Comment: ^thanks changed it to that just now.

Comment: I updated the post with `like` and `unlike` function @tymeJV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing in the `event_id`, pass the object to the `like` and `unLike` functions and update the object in success handler.

**HTML**

```
<a ng-hide='event.liked' ng-click="like(event)">Like</a>
<a ng-show='event.liked' ng-click="unLike(event)">Unlike</a>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.like = function(event) {
    var url = 'www.server.com?type=unlike&event_id=' + event.event_id;
    $http.post(url).success(function (data) {
        event.liked = true;
        console.log('success like');
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('fail like');
    });
};
$scope.unLike = function(event) {
    var url = 'www.server.com?type=unlike&event_id=' + event.event_id;
    $http.post(url).success(function (data) {
        event.liked = null;
        console.log('success unlike');
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('fail unlike');
    });
};
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you so much for both suggestions!